# Calculation of all possible mutations of a nonogram

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

I need to build a nonogram solver according to a very specific recipe. For each row, I need to calculate all possible mutations, and then check if that row would still make the puzzle valid. For those unknown with nonograms, here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram). A row is nothing more than a boolean array, where 'true' means it's marked, and 'false' would mean its' not.

The problem here lies within 'all possible mutations'. Let's look at an example. If a row would have the numbers 2, 1 and 3 next to it, the row would need at least 8 blocks of space (2+1+3, +2 for empty spaces necessary). So, if the row is 8 spaces long, there's no problem. However, if the row is larger than that, even by a small margin, it'd be very hard (NP hard even) to calculate all possible permutations. I cannot think of an algorithm which correctly does this. Can anyone help?

EDIT: It seems my question was unclear, so I'll try to clarify it a bit.

In the puzzle, let's assume we have a 1x4 puzzle, 1 row, 4 columns. Now let's look at the row:

```
2 1: _ _ _ _
```

Like this, the only possible answer is

```
2 1: X X _ X
```

But what if the puzzle was 1x8?

```
2 1: _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

I'm looking for an algorithm that can find all permutations of such a line.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this would be tagged [tag:java].

Comment: You are right, it did not need the tag Java. I'm writing this in java, so I added the tag unthinkingly, but the solution to such a problem shouldn't be language specific. Thanks for fixing my tags!

Comment: Voted reopen because this is an interesting twist to the classic permutation problem and this problem appears to be fully specified in the question. Also, this problem, like the classic permutation problem, has a canonical answer (though of course there's a recursive and non-recursive variant).

Comment: I have an answer to this. If nobody else will reopen this I'll simply copy paste this question and ask it again and answer it myself. I'll keep that version up until this question is reopened.

Comment: Side note: the answer is related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521043/algorithm-that-takes-an-integer-and-returns-all-possible-format-of-addition

Comment: @slebetman It seems the question isn't getting reopened although I've clarified the problem, and I still don't have an answer. If you have a solution for this, would you mind sharing it?