# Calculating all possible row combination that satisfies its row constraint in a nonogram

Tags: algorithm, permutation

So basicly what I'm asking is the exactly same as what this person asked a year ago: [Calculation of all possible mutations of a nonogram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127342/calculation-of-all-possible-mutations-of-a-nonogram) which was closed as unclear, though I can't see why it would be.

To recap the exact problem. In nonograms row and columns can be filled in different ways that must satisfy a constriction.

As an example, if a row has the constraint [2,3,2] and length 10, it means 2 adjecent cells must be filled, then a blank, then 3 adjecent, a blank and finally 2 adjecent.

All the possible combinations would then be:

[2,3,2] : x x _ x x x _ x x _ 
[2,3,2] : x x _ x x x _ _ x x 
[2,3,2] : x x _ _ x x x _ x x 
[2,3,2] : _ x x _ x x x _ x x

I imagined it would be quite easy creating a general function for calculating all possible combinations for any row length and constraint, but I've been trying this the whole weekend and it's driving me insane! Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show *any* of the work you have done, and how it is deficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you think of this as a combinatorial question:

Given the constraint `[2,3,2]`, you basically have to have the following:
`xx`, `_`, `xxx`, `_`, `xx`.
The question left is where do you put the rest of your spaces. Since you have 3 sets of `x`s, you have 4 places to put them. Your example shows putting the only available space after the third set, aster the second, after the first and before the first.

To generalize, work out how many free spaces you have (`n = total length - number of`x`s - (number of sets - 1)` ). Now use combinatorics 101 to figure out all the combinations of putting `k` identical spaces into `n` possible places. Once you have the list - you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I got a working implementation now. What really helped me was to think in terms lists containing the amount of blanks for each possible place(as you suggested). Instead of trying to calculate the exact solutions like in my example which would be [[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1],[1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1]]. It was really helpful to instead calculate the lists of combinations of possible blanks, which would for my example be: [[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0]] and from there compute the actual row combination.

Comment: As well as solving it recursively. I was a fool to even attempt solving such a combinatoric problem without recursion.