# Python: Find all possible combinations of parts of a given number

Tags: python-3.x, math

I am solving a puzzle. Suppose I have a positive integer, let's say "8" (it could be any positive integer).

How can I create an algorithm to generate the all possible sums of positive integer that will equate to my integer? For example:

```
8 = 7+1
8 = 6+2
8 = 6+1+1
8 = 5+3
8 = 5+2+1
8 = 5+1+1+1
8 = 4+4
8 = 4+3+1
8 = 4+2+2
8 = 4+2+1+1
```

and so on.

Comment: Does `8 = 8` count?

Comment: no, but if it appears in the output, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this code useful:

```
def sum_to_n(n, size, limit=None):
    """Produce all lists of `size` positive integers in decreasing order
    that add up to `n`."""
    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = (n + size - 1) // size
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):
        for tail in sum_to_n(n - i, size - 1, i):
            yield [i] + tail

for partition in sum_to_n(6, 3):
    print (partition)

[2, 2, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[4, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thank You, this will help me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar question :

[Algorithm that takes an integer and returns all possible format of addition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521043/algorithm-that-takes-an-integer-and-returns-all-possible-format-of-addition)

Java implementation link

[ALGORITHM PRACTICE – POSSIBLE ADDITION COMBINATIONS FOR ANY GIVEN NUMBER](https://rahulj51.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/algorithm-practice-possible-addition-combinations-for-any-given-number/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Cid-EL who missed just a bit to iterate through:

```
def sum_to_n(n, size, limit=None):
    """Produce all lists of `size` positive integers in decreasing order
    that add up to `n`."""
    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = (n + size - 1) // size
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):
        for tail in sum_to_n(n - i, size - 1, i):
            yield [i] + tail

def n_sum(n):
    ret_list = []
    for s in range(1, n):
        for m in sum_to_n(n, s):
            ret_list.append(m)
    ret_list.append([1]*n)
    return ret_list

# You would use this as a command:
>>> n_sum(8)
[[8], [4, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 1], [3, 3, 2], [4, 2, 2], [4, 3, 1], [5, 2, 1], [6, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2, 1], [3, 3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 1, 1], [3, 2, 1, 1, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: @V.Petretto Please accept an answer if it has solved your question.