# Python: How to calculate combinations of parts of a given number, giving the number, list lenght, first and last number

Tags: python, math, combinatorics

I'm very stuck on this ( probably because I'm new to computer programming ).
I have the following code, from the question: [[Python: Find all possible combinations of parts of a given number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616841/python-find-all-possible-combinations-of-parts-of-a-given-number/37617708?noredirect=1#comment62719215_37617708])

```
def sum_to_n(n, size, limit=None):
    """Produce all lists of `size` positive integers in decreasing order
    that add up to `n`."""
    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = (n + size - 1) // size
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):
        for tail in sum_to_n(n - i, size - 1, i):
            yield [i] + tail

for partition in sum_to_n(8, 3):
    print (partition)

[6, 1, 1]
[5, 2, 1]
[4, 3, 1]
[4, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 2]
```

Is it very useful but I'm trying to modify it in order to set some options. Suppose I want to have only the results in wich the first number of the list is 4 and the last of the list is 1.
At the moment I use this solution:

```
def sum_to_n(n,first, last, size, limit=None):
    if size == 1:
        yield [n]
        return
    if limit is None:
        limit = n
    start = (n + size - 1) // size
    stop = min(limit, n - size + 1) + 1
    for i in range(start, stop):
        if i <=first:
            for tail in sum_to_n(n - i,first,last, size - 1, i):
                ll=len(tail)
                if tail[ll-1]==last:
                    yield [i] + tail

for i in sum_to_n(8,4,1,3):
    if i[0]==4 and i[size-1]==1:
        print(i)
    if i[0]>4:
        break

[4,3,1]
```

But with larger integers the program is doing a lot of unwanted work.
For example, the `for i in range(start, stop):` computes all the possible first numbers of the list and not only the "first" parameter nedded and the function does not work without it.
Someone can suggest a better and faster solution to call the function giving the parameters needed in order to have only the requested computations ?

Comment: When I run your first code in Python 3.5.2, I get the same lists but in reverse order. Do you actually get the order that you show?

Comment: no it's only for example, is not the actual output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the first number, you just need to solve if for the last one.

In your example, that would give something like:

```
for res in sum_to_n(n=8-4, last=1, size=3-1):
   print([4] + res)
```

Comment: Yes interesting and inspiring. Finally I found a way using your idea. I subtracted from the sum "n" the first and the last number and called the function only for the "in between" numbers. Then simply join the three parts: first, res, last. In this way is faster.